# Manipulating CSV data stored as a string Python

Tags: python, string, csv

I have an API string which responds with an XML page, and has my data stored as CSV in the "data" tag (I can request it in JSON format but I haven't been able to handle the data correctly in my Python script in that format).

```
<reports.getAccountsStatsResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:com:gigya:api" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:com:gigya:api http://socialize-api.gigya.com/schema">
<statusCode>200</statusCode>
<errorCode>0</errorCode>
<statusReason>OK</statusReason>
<callId>ae1b3f13ba1c4e62ad3120afb1269c76</callId>
<time>2015-09-01T09:01:46.511Z</time>
<headers>
<header>date</header>
<header>initRegistrations</header>
<header>registrations</header>
<header>siteLogins</header>
<header>newUsers</header>
</headers>
<data xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="q1:string">
"date","initRegistrations","registrations","siteLogins","newUsers" "01/01/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/02/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/03/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/04/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/05/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/06/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/07/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/08/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/09/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/10/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/11/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/12/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/13/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/14/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/15/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/16/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/17/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/18/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/19/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/20/2015","34","34","72","34" "01/21/2015","33","23","58","23" "01/22/2015","19","19","49","19" "01/23/2015","21","21","50","21" "01/24/2015","1","1","2","1" "01/25/2015","0","0","0","0" "01/26/2015","8","4","49","4" "01/27/2015","8","8","35","8" "01/28/2015","4","2","16","2" "01/29/2015","7","7","27","7" "01/30/2015","69","58","516","58" "01/31/2015","9","6","76","6" "02/01/2015","0","0","2","0" "02/02/2015","304","203","2317","203" "02/03/2015","122","93","786","93" "02/04/2015","69","47","435","47" "02/05/2015","93","64","677","64" "02/06/2015","294","255","1327","255" "02/07/2015","0","0","0","0" "02/08/2015","0","0","0","0" "02/09/2015","0","0","3","0" "02/10/2015","1","0","1","0" "02/11/2015","3","3","7","3" "02/12/2015","0","0","0","0" "02/13/2015","2","2","4","2" "02/14/2015","0","0","1","0" "02/15/2015","0","0","0","0" "02/16/2015","0","0","0","0" "02/17/2015","3","3","7","3" "02/18/2015","0","0","0","0" "02/19/2015","1","1","3","1" "02/20/2015","3","3","10","3" "02/21/2015","0","0","0","0" "02/22/2015","0","0","1","0" "02/23/2015","1","1","4","1" "02/24/2015","0","0","1","0" "02/25/2015","0","0","0","0" "02/26/2015","0","0","0","0" "02/27/2015","0","0","1","0" "02/28/2015","1","1","2","1" "03/01/2015","1","1","3","1" "03/02/2015","19","9","348","9" "03/03/2015","14","9","132","9" "03/04/2015","4","4","41","4" "03/05/2015","8","5","101","5" "03/06/2015","6","5","71","5" "03/07/2015","8","4","42","4" "03/08/2015","7","4","45","4" "03/09/2015","5","4","30","4" "03/10/2015","7","7","39","7" "03/11/2015","9","9","41","9" "03/12/2015","1","1","20","1" "03/13/2015","3","3","26","3" "03/14/2015","2","0","21","0" "03/15/2015","3","3","28","3" "03/16/2015","3","3","38","3" "03/17/2015","4","4","43","4" "03/18/2015","5","3","45","3" "03/19/2015","19","16","108","16" "03/20/2015","11","8","96","8" "03/21/2015","276","261","807","261" "03/22/2015","197","192","604","192" "03/23/2015","0","0","3","0" "03/24/2015","1","1","4","1" "03/25/2015","181","166","401","166" "03/26/2015","124","109","265","109" "03/27/2015","53","47","124","47" "03/28/2015","41","39","99","39" "03/29/2015","75","65","173","65" "03/30/2015","249","239","536","239" "03/31/2015","222","212","487","212" "04/01/2015","40","29","394","29" "04/02/2015","16","10","132","10" "04/03/2015","13","10","125","10" "04/04/2015","6","4","49","4" "04/05/2015","2","1","46","1" "04/06/2015","4","3","38","3" "04/07/2015","1","0","32","0" "04/08/2015","4","2","16","2" "04/09/2015","9","8","30","8" "04/10/2015","31","29","96","29" "04/11/2015","17","14","90","14" "04/12/2015","10","7","46","7" "04/13/2015","19","13","69","13" "04/14/2015","63","58","199","58" "04/15/2015","17","16","58","16" "04/16/2015","13","12","41","12" "04/17/2015","7","5","51","5" "04/18/2015","51","46","165","46" "04/19/2015","51","45","179","45" "04/20/2015","28","21","110","21" "04/21/2015","32","24","290","24" "04/22/2015","47","31","329","31" "04/23/2015","30","27","183","27" "04/24/2015","71","65","284","65" "04/25/2015","25","17","268","17" "04/26/2015","26","24","268","24" "04/27/2015","72","67","172","67" "04/28/2015","28","25","96","25" "04/29/2015","72","48","159","48" "04/30/2015","50","22","136","22" "05/01/2015","33","23","126","23" "05/02/2015","22","17","112","17" "05/03/2015","31","21","169","21" "05/04/2015","29","21","182","21" "05/05/2015","12","10","24","10" "05/06/2015","369","354","790","354" "05/07/2015","409","401","839","401" "05/08/2015","258","253","539","253" "05/09/2015","227","221","469","221" "05/10/2015","138","134","297","134" "05/11/2015","14","13","32","13" "05/12/2015","57","24","452","24" "05/13/2015","23","12","300","12" "05/14/2015","7","5","70","5" "05/15/2015","7","6","15","6" "05/16/2015","3","3","7","3" "05/17/2015","3","3","8","3" "05/18/2015","2","4","4","2" "05/19/2015","10","16","24","8" "05/20/2015","4","8","10","4" "05/21/2015","7","12","14","6" "05/22/2015","9","14","33","7" "05/23/2015","9","14","19","7" "05/24/2015","16","32","39","16" "05/25/2015","11","9","21","7" "05/26/2015","23","16","87","16" "05/27/2015","30","24","87","24" "05/28/2015","12","12","39","12" "05/29/2015","14","12","37","12" "05/30/2015","8","7","19","7" "05/31/2015","5","4","17","4" "06/01/2015","10","10","31","10" "06/02/2015","23","20","95","20" "06/03/2015","11","9","31","9" "06/04/2015","14","13","36","13" "06/05/2015","12","11","27","11" "06/06/2015","8","6","20","6" "06/07/2015","9","9","21","9" "06/08/2015","16","16","37","16" "06/09/2015","24","17","40","17" "06/10/2015","8","8","34","8" "06/11/2015","46","27","464","27" "06/12/2015","45","23","383","23" "06/13/2015","12","9","143","9" "06/14/2015","22","15","112","15" "06/15/2015","14","13","74","13" "06/16/2015","63","56","197","56" "06/17/2015","28","25","114","25" "06/18/2015","17","15","85","15" "06/19/2015","143","135","460","135" "06/20/2015","54","46","217","46" "06/21/2015","60","55","211","55" "06/22/2015","91","78","249","78" "06/23/2015","99","87","295","87" "06/24/2015","115","103","315","103" "06/25/2015","455","380","964","380" "06/26/2015","585","489","1144","489" "06/27/2015","345","300","695","300" "06/28/2015","349","320","783","320" "06/29/2015","113","98","362","98" "06/30/2015","128","113","424","113" "07/01/2015","115","99","277","99" "07/02/2015","73","65","323","65" "07/03/2015","22","16","184","16" "07/04/2015","13","12","69","12" "07/05/2015","15","12","71","12" "07/06/2015","31","25","107","25" "07/07/2015","15","10","63","10" "07/08/2015","16","12","60","12" "07/09/2015","35","32","103","32" "07/10/2015","22","19","72","19" "07/11/2015","7","7","25","7" "07/12/2015","4","4","27","4" "07/13/2015","81","73","195","73" "07/14/2015","60","53","157","53" "07/15/2015","44","40","115","40" "07/16/2015","40","40","112","40" "07/17/2015","27","23","64","23" "07/18/2015","15","11","56","11" "07/19/2015","19","14","63","14" "07/20/2015","21","17","48","17" "07/21/2015","11","10","30","10" "07/22/2015","13","12","40","12" "07/23/2015","9","6","43","6" "07/24/2015","9","8","32","8" "07/25/2015","8","5","20","5" "07/26/2015","20","18","64","18" "07/27/2015","15","14","80","14" "07/28/2015","9","8","48","8" "07/29/2015","21","13","88","13" "07/30/2015","9","5","92","5" "07/31/2015","4","3","81","3" "08/01/2015","4","3","23","3" "08/02/2015","11","5","29","5" "08/03/2015","19","17","50","17" "08/04/2015","15","10","32","10" "08/05/2015","14","9","31","9" "08/06/2015","26","5","338","5" "08/07/2015","22","13","182","13" "08/08/2015","9","7","72","7" "08/09/2015","7","4","58","4" "08/10/2015","17","14","88","14" "08/11/2015","23","17","100","17" "08/12/2015","20","20","62","20" "08/13/2015","23","21","81","21" "08/14/2015","30","26","136","26" "08/15/2015","12","7","59","7" "08/16/2015","12","8","61","8" "08/17/2015","68","46","331","46" "08/18/2015","72","48","327","48" "08/19/2015","149","75","542","75" "08/20/2015","95","59","358","59" "08/21/2015","93","54","342","54" "08/22/2015","69","40","300","40" "08/23/2015","150","103","505","103" "08/24/2015","39","30","105","30"
</data>
</reports.getAccountsStatsResponse>
```

And in JSON format:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "statusReason": "OK",
  "callId": "99949da72d034b04ba910c91704ba4c0",
  "time": "2015-09-01T09:19:30.569Z",
  "headers": [
    "date",
    "initRegistrations",
    "registrations",
    "siteLogins",
    "newUsers"
  ],
  "data": "\"date\",\"initRegistrations\",\"registrations\",\"siteLogins\",\"newUsers\"\r\n\"01/01/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/02/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/03/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/04/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/05/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/06/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/07/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/08/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/09/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/10/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/11/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/12/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/13/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/14/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/15/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/16/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/17/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/18/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/19/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/20/2015\",\"34\",\"34\",\"72\",\"34\"\r\n\"01/21/2015\",\"33\",\"23\",\"58\",\"23\"\r\n\"01/22/2015\",\"19\",\"19\",\"49\",\"19\"\r\n\"01/23/2015\",\"21\",\"21\",\"50\",\"21\"\r\n\"01/24/2015\",\"1\",\"1\",\"2\",\"1\"\r\n\"01/25/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"01/26/2015\",\"8\",\"4\",\"49\",\"4\"\r\n\"01/27/2015\",\"8\",\"8\",\"35\",\"8\"\r\n\"01/28/2015\",\"4\",\"2\",\"16\",\"2\"\r\n\"01/29/2015\",\"7\",\"7\",\"27\",\"7\"\r\n\"01/30/2015\",\"69\",\"58\",\"516\",\"58\"\r\n\"01/31/2015\",\"9\",\"6\",\"76\",\"6\"\r\n\"02/01/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"2\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/02/2015\",\"304\",\"203\",\"2317\",\"203\"\r\n\"02/03/2015\",\"122\",\"93\",\"786\",\"93\"\r\n\"02/04/2015\",\"69\",\"47\",\"435\",\"47\"\r\n\"02/05/2015\",\"93\",\"64\",\"677\",\"64\"\r\n\"02/06/2015\",\"294\",\"255\",\"1327\",\"255\"\r\n\"02/07/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/08/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/09/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"3\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/10/2015\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/11/2015\",\"3\",\"3\",\"7\",\"3\"\r\n\"02/12/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/13/2015\",\"2\",\"2\",\"4\",\"2\"\r\n\"02/14/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/15/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/16/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/17/2015\",\"3\",\"3\",\"7\",\"3\"\r\n\"02/18/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/19/2015\",\"1\",\"1\",\"3\",\"1\"\r\n\"02/20/2015\",\"3\",\"3\",\"10\",\"3\"\r\n\"02/21/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/22/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/23/2015\",\"1\",\"1\",\"4\",\"1\"\r\n\"02/24/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/25/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/26/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/27/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\"\r\n\"02/28/2015\",\"1\",\"1\",\"2\",\"1\"\r\n\"03/01/2015\",\"1\",\"1\",\"3\",\"1\"\r\n\"03/02/2015\",\"19\",\"9\",\"348\",\"9\"\r\n\"03/03/2015\",\"14\",\"9\",\"132\",\"9\"\r\n\"03/04/2015\",\"4\",\"4\",\"41\",\"4\"\r\n\"03/05/2015\",\"8\",\"5\",\"101\",\"5\"\r\n\"03/06/2015\",\"6\",\"5\",\"71\",\"5\"\r\n\"03/07/2015\",\"8\",\"4\",\"42\",\"4\"\r\n\"03/08/2015\",\"7\",\"4\",\"45\",\"4\"\r\n\"03/09/2015\",\"5\",\"4\",\"30\",\"4\"\r\n\"03/10/2015\",\"7\",\"7\",\"39\",\"7\"\r\n\"03/11/2015\",\"9\",\"9\",\"41\",\"9\"\r\n\"03/12/2015\",\"1\",\"1\",\"20\",\"1\"\r\n\"03/13/2015\",\"3\",\"3\",\"26\",\"3\"\r\n\"03/14/2015\",\"2\",\"0\",\"21\",\"0\"\r\n\"03/15/2015\",\"3\",\"3\",\"28\",\"3\"\r\n\"03/16/2015\",\"3\",\"3\",\"38\",\"3\"\r\n\"03/17/2015\",\"4\",\"4\",\"43\",\"4\"\r\n\"03/18/2015\",\"5\",\"3\",\"45\",\"3\"\r\n\"03/19/2015\",\"19\",\"16\",\"108\",\"16\"\r\n\"03/20/2015\",\"11\",\"8\",\"96\",\"8\"\r\n\"03/21/2015\",\"276\",\"261\",\"807\",\"261\"\r\n\"03/22/2015\",\"197\",\"192\",\"604\",\"192\"\r\n\"03/23/2015\",\"0\",\"0\",\"3\",\"0\"\r\n\"03/24/2015\",\"1\",\"1\",\"4\",\"1\"\r\n\"03/25/2015\",\"181\",\"166\",\"401\",\"166\"\r\n\"03/26/2015\",\"124\",\"109\",\"265\",\"109\"\r\n\"03/27/2015\",\"53\",\"47\",\"124\",\"47\"\r\n\"03/28/2015\",\"41\",\"39\",\"99\",\"39\"\r\n\"03/29/2015\",\"75\",\"65\",\"173\",\"65\"\r\n\"03/30/2015\",\"249\",\"239\",\"536\",\"239\"\r\n\"03/31/2015\",\"222\",\"212\",\"487\",\"212\"\r\n\"04/01/2015\",\"40\",\"29\",\"394\",\"29\"\r\n\"04/02/2015\",\"16\",\"10\",\"132\",\"10\"\r\n\"04/03/2015\",\"13\",\"10\",\"125\",\"10\"\r\n\"04/04/2015\",\"6\",\"4\",\"49\",\"4\"\r\n\"04/05/2015\",\"2\",\"1\",\"46\",\"1\"\r\n\"04/06/2015\",\"4\",\"3\",\"38\",\"3\"\r\n\"04/07/2015\",\"1\",\"0\",\"32\",\"0\"\r\n\"04/08/2015\",\"4\",\"2\",\"16\",\"2\"\r\n\"04/09/2015\",\"9\",\"8\",\"30\",\"8\"\r\n\"04/10/2015\",\"31\",\"29\",\"96\",\"29\"\r\n\"04/11/2015\",\"17\",\"14\",\"90\",\"14\"\r\n\"04/12/2015\",\"10\",\"7\",\"46\",\"7\"\r\n\"04/13/2015\",\"19\",\"13\",\"69\",\"13\"\r\n\"04/14/2015\",\"63\",\"58\",\"199\",\"58\"\r\n\"04/15/2015\",\"17\",\"16\",\"58\",\"16\"\r\n\"04/16/2015\",\"13\",\"12\",\"41\",\"12\"\r\n\"04/17/2015\",\"7\",\"5\",\"51\",\"5\"\r\n\"04/18/2015\",\"51\",\"46\",\"165\",\"46\"\r\n\"04/19/2015\",\"51\",\"45\",\"179\",\"45\"\r\n\"04/20/2015\",\"28\",\"21\",\"110\",\"21\"\r\n\"04/21/2015\",\"32\",\"24\",\"290\",\"24\"\r\n\"04/22/2015\",\"47\",\"31\",\"329\",\"31\"\r\n\"04/23/2015\",\"30\",\"27\",\"183\",\"27\"\r\n\"04/24/2015\",\"71\",\"65\",\"284\",\"65\"\r\n\"04/25/2015\",\"25\",\"17\",\"268\",\"17\"\r\n\"04/26/2015\",\"26\",\"24\",\"268\",\"24\"\r\n\"04/27/2015\",\"72\",\"67\",\"172\",\"67\"\r\n\"04/28/2015\",\"28\",\"25\",\"96\",\"25\"\r\n\"04/29/2015\",\"72\",\"48\",\"159\",\"48\"\r\n\"04/30/2015\",\"50\",\"22\",\"136\",\"22\"\r\n\"05/01/2015\",\"33\",\"23\",\"126\",\"23\"\r\n\"05/02/2015\",\"22\",\"17\",\"112\",\"17\"\r\n\"05/03/2015\",\"31\",\"21\",\"169\",\"21\"\r\n\"05/04/2015\",\"29\",\"21\",\"182\",\"21\"\r\n\"05/05/2015\",\"12\",\"10\",\"24\",\"10\"\r\n\"05/06/2015\",\"369\",\"354\",\"790\",\"354\"\r\n\"05/07/2015\",\"409\",\"401\",\"839\",\"401\"\r\n\"05/08/2015\",\"258\",\"253\",\"539\",\"253\"\r\n\"05/09/2015\",\"227\",\"221\",\"469\",\"221\"\r\n\"05/10/2015\",\"138\",\"134\",\"297\",\"134\"\r\n\"05/11/2015\",\"14\",\"13\",\"32\",\"13\"\r\n\"05/12/2015\",\"57\",\"24\",\"452\",\"24\"\r\n\"05/13/2015\",\"23\",\"12\",\"300\",\"12\"\r\n\"05/14/2015\",\"7\",\"5\",\"70\",\"5\"\r\n\"05/15/2015\",\"7\",\"6\",\"15\",\"6\"\r\n\"05/16/2015\",\"3\",\"3\",\"7\",\"3\"\r\n\"05/17/2015\",\"3\",\"3\",\"8\",\"3\"\r\n\"05/18/2015\",\"2\",\"4\",\"4\",\"2\"\r\n\"05/19/2015\",\"10\",\"16\",\"24\",\"8\"\r\n\"05/20/2015\",\"4\",\"8\",\"10\",\"4\"\r\n\"05/21/2015\",\"7\",\"12\",\"14\",\"6\"\r\n\"05/22/2015\",\"9\",\"14\",\"33\",\"7\"\r\n\"05/23/2015\",\"9\",\"14\",\"19\",\"7\"\r\n\"05/24/2015\",\"16\",\"32\",\"39\",\"16\"\r\n\"05/25/2015\",\"11\",\"9\",\"21\",\"7\"\r\n\"05/26/2015\",\"23\",\"16\",\"87\",\"16\"\r\n\"05/27/2015\",\"30\",\"24\",\"87\",\"24\"\r\n\"05/28/2015\",\"12\",\"12\",\"39\",\"12\"\r\n\"05/29/2015\",\"14\",\"12\",\"37\",\"12\"\r\n\"05/30/2015\",\"8\",\"7\",\"19\",\"7\"\r\n\"05/31/2015\",\"5\",\"4\",\"17\",\"4\"\r\n\"06/01/2015\",\"10\",\"10\",\"31\",\"10\"\r\n\"06/02/2015\",\"23\",\"20\",\"95\",\"20\"\r\n\"06/03/2015\",\"11\",\"9\",\"31\",\"9\"\r\n\"06/04/2015\",\"14\",\"13\",\"36\",\"13\"\r\n\"06/05/2015\",\"12\",\"11\",\"27\",\"11\"\r\n\"06/06/2015\",\"8\",\"6\",\"20\",\"6\"\r\n\"06/07/2015\",\"9\",\"9\",\"21\",\"9\"\r\n\"06/08/2015\",\"16\",\"16\",\"37\",\"16\"\r\n\"06/09/2015\",\"24\",\"17\",\"40\",\"17\"\r\n\"06/10/2015\",\"8\",\"8\",\"34\",\"8\"\r\n\"06/11/2015\",\"46\",\"27\",\"464\",\"27\"\r\n\"06/12/2015\",\"45\",\"23\",\"383\",\"23\"\r\n\"06/13/2015\",\"12\",\"9\",\"143\",\"9\"\r\n\"06/14/2015\",\"22\",\"15\",\"112\",\"15\"\r\n\"06/15/2015\",\"14\",\"13\",\"74\",\"13\"\r\n\"06/16/2015\",\"63\",\"56\",\"197\",\"56\"\r\n\"06/17/2015\",\"28\",\"25\",\"114\",\"25\"\r\n\"06/18/2015\",\"17\",\"15\",\"85\",\"15\"\r\n\"06/19/2015\",\"143\",\"135\",\"460\",\"135\"\r\n\"06/20/2015\",\"54\",\"46\",\"217\",\"46\"\r\n\"06/21/2015\",\"60\",\"55\",\"211\",\"55\"\r\n\"06/22/2015\",\"91\",\"78\",\"249\",\"78\"\r\n\"06/23/2015\",\"99\",\"87\",\"295\",\"87\"\r\n\"06/24/2015\",\"115\",\"103\",\"315\",\"103\"\r\n\"06/25/2015\",\"455\",\"380\",\"964\",\"380\"\r\n\"06/26/2015\",\"585\",\"489\",\"1144\",\"489\"\r\n\"06/27/2015\",\"345\",\"300\",\"695\",\"300\"\r\n\"06/28/2015\",\"349\",\"320\",\"783\",\"320\"\r\n\"06/29/2015\",\"113\",\"98\",\"362\",\"98\"\r\n\"06/30/2015\",\"128\",\"113\",\"424\",\"113\"\r\n\"07/01/2015\",\"115\",\"99\",\"277\",\"99\"\r\n\"07/02/2015\",\"73\",\"65\",\"323\",\"65\"\r\n\"07/03/2015\",\"22\",\"16\",\"184\",\"16\"\r\n\"07/04/2015\",\"13\",\"12\",\"69\",\"12\"\r\n\"07/05/2015\",\"15\",\"12\",\"71\",\"12\"\r\n\"07/06/2015\",\"31\",\"25\",\"107\",\"25\"\r\n\"07/07/2015\",\"15\",\"10\",\"63\",\"10\"\r\n\"07/08/2015\",\"16\",\"12\",\"60\",\"12\"\r\n\"07/09/2015\",\"35\",\"32\",\"103\",\"32\"\r\n\"07/10/2015\",\"22\",\"19\",\"72\",\"19\"\r\n\"07/11/2015\",\"7\",\"7\",\"25\",\"7\"\r\n\"07/12/2015\",\"4\",\"4\",\"27\",\"4\"\r\n\"07/13/2015\",\"81\",\"73\",\"195\",\"73\"\r\n\"07/14/2015\",\"60\",\"53\",\"157\",\"53\"\r\n\"07/15/2015\",\"44\",\"40\",\"115\",\"40\"\r\n\"07/16/2015\",\"40\",\"40\",\"112\",\"40\"\r\n\"07/17/2015\",\"27\",\"23\",\"64\",\"23\"\r\n\"07/18/2015\",\"15\",\"11\",\"56\",\"11\"\r\n\"07/19/2015\",\"19\",\"14\",\"63\",\"14\"\r\n\"07/20/2015\",\"21\",\"17\",\"48\",\"17\"\r\n\"07/21/2015\",\"11\",\"10\",\"30\",\"10\"\r\n\"07/22/2015\",\"13\",\"12\",\"40\",\"12\"\r\n\"07/23/2015\",\"9\",\"6\",\"43\",\"6\"\r\n\"07/24/2015\",\"9\",\"8\",\"32\",\"8\"\r\n\"07/25/2015\",\"8\",\"5\",\"20\",\"5\"\r\n\"07/26/2015\",\"20\",\"18\",\"64\",\"18\"\r\n\"07/27/2015\",\"15\",\"14\",\"80\",\"14\"\r\n\"07/28/2015\",\"9\",\"8\",\"48\",\"8\"\r\n\"07/29/2015\",\"21\",\"13\",\"88\",\"13\"\r\n\"07/30/2015\",\"9\",\"5\",\"92\",\"5\"\r\n\"07/31/2015\",\"4\",\"3\",\"81\",\"3\"\r\n\"08/01/2015\",\"4\",\"3\",\"23\",\"3\"\r\n\"08/02/2015\",\"11\",\"5\",\"29\",\"5\"\r\n\"08/03/2015\",\"19\",\"17\",\"50\",\"17\"\r\n\"08/04/2015\",\"15\",\"10\",\"32\",\"10\"\r\n\"08/05/2015\",\"14\",\"9\",\"31\",\"9\"\r\n\"08/06/2015\",\"26\",\"5\",\"338\",\"5\"\r\n\"08/07/2015\",\"22\",\"13\",\"182\",\"13\"\r\n\"08/08/2015\",\"9\",\"7\",\"72\",\"7\"\r\n\"08/09/2015\",\"7\",\"4\",\"58\",\"4\"\r\n\"08/10/2015\",\"17\",\"14\",\"88\",\"14\"\r\n\"08/11/2015\",\"23\",\"17\",\"100\",\"17\"\r\n\"08/12/2015\",\"20\",\"20\",\"62\",\"20\"\r\n\"08/13/2015\",\"23\",\"21\",\"81\",\"21\"\r\n\"08/14/2015\",\"30\",\"26\",\"136\",\"26\"\r\n\"08/15/2015\",\"12\",\"7\",\"59\",\"7\"\r\n\"08/16/2015\",\"12\",\"8\",\"61\",\"8\"\r\n\"08/17/2015\",\"68\",\"46\",\"331\",\"46\"\r\n\"08/18/2015\",\"72\",\"48\",\"327\",\"48\"\r\n\"08/19/2015\",\"149\",\"75\",\"542\",\"75\"\r\n\"08/20/2015\",\"95\",\"59\",\"358\",\"59\"\r\n\"08/21/2015\",\"93\",\"54\",\"342\",\"54\"\r\n\"08/22/2015\",\"69\",\"40\",\"300\",\"40\"\r\n\"08/23/2015\",\"150\",\"103\",\"505\",\"103\"\r\n\"08/24/2015\",\"39\",\"30\",\"105\",\"30\"\r\n"
}
```

Firstly, I would like to store the text from the "data" tag by referencing the name of it, but I've currently only had success by using this following:

```
response = requests.get(url)
root = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)

dataString = root[6].text
```

Is there a separate command to be able to specify the name of the tag?

Next, my goal is to loop through different URL's (which correspond to different accounts), and append the name of those accounts to the end of the data. Is this possible, given that the data is stored as a string and I would need to add it to the end of each row? As a follow up, what's the best convention for saving multiple values in a variable to be able to loop through i.e. the list of accounts?

Apologies if this is unclear, I'm happy to provide any more information if it means anybody can help.

Comment: You're saying you can also get the data JSON-formatted. If so, could you please provide the snippet using JSON-formatted data?

Comment: Editted with JSON format

Comment: Using the JSON-formatted response extracting the data is easy since JSON-data can be accessed like a dictionary: `data = response['data']`

Comment: Okay, so if I have my data in that format, I would need to loop through each of the values in the list and append an extra string to the end to satisfy by account naming needs?

Comment: That's the point I could not follow. Could you please describ this a bit more detailed using some sample snippets extending your question? Btw, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Okay so the data I extract has no field which describes what it belongs to, so once I gather all of my data from the different sources, I won't know which is for which account. I want to add data from my own variable which contains the name, to the end of each row. I haven't tried anything in the XML example as I couldn't find anything on it. I'm trying a for loop on the "data" variable you described currently, to append to the end of each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, you have a specific URL for each user and you want to collect data for all users given.

However, since you are not able to get the username out of the response you have to combine the response with the username corresponding to the URL the request was sent to. If so, you could use a dictionary to store the data of your response since the JSON-format is equivalent to Python's dictionary.

The code below simply iterates through a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) containing the different user names and the corresponding URL. For each URL a request is sent, the data is extracted from the JSON-formatted response and stored in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with the username as a key. This dictionary is then stored ([`.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update)) in a kind of main dictionary containing all your collected datasets.

```
# replace names 'url_xyz' with corresponding names and url
users = {('Albert', 'url_albert'), ('Steven', 'url_steven'), ('Mike', 'url_mike')}

all_data = dict()

for name, url in users:
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response['data'].replace('\"', '')
    all_data.update({name: data})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Albert.

Your JSON suggestion let me control the data in a much better way. The code below is what I ended up with to get to my desired output. Now just to work out how to convert the date from MM/DD/YYYY into DD/MM/YYYY.

```
startDate = '2015-01-01' # Must be in format YYYY-MM-DD
endDate = '2015-12-31' # Must be in format YYYY-MM-DD
dimensions = 'date' # Available dimensions are 'date' and 'cid'
format = 'json'
dataFormat = 'json'
measures = 'initRegistrations,registrations,siteLogins,newUsers'
allData = []

# Construct API URL
for i in range(0,len(apiKey)):

      url = ('https://reports.eu1.gigya.com/reports.getAccountsStats?secret=' + secret + '&apiKey=' + apiKey[i] + \
            '&uid=' + uid + '&startDate=' + startDate + '&endDate=' + endDate + '&dimensions='+ dimensions +\
            '&measures=' + measures + '&format=' + format + '&dataFormat=' + dataFormat)

      response = requests.get(url)

      json = response.json()
      data = json['data']

      if i == 0:
            headers = json['headers']
            headers.append('brand')

            for x in range(0,len(data)):
                  data[x].append(brand[i])

            brandData = [headers] + data
      else:
            for x in range(0,len(data)):
                  data[x].append(brand[i])

            brandData = data

      allData += brandData


with open("testDataJSON.csv", "wb") as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f)
      writer.writerows(allData)
```

I don't know how well this follows best practice for Python but as I said, I am very new to it.

Comment: Please take care that Stackoverflow is not a forum but a question-and-answer-platform.
A quick string approach just to rearrange day and month would be the following: `date = '09/01/2015'
date_parts = date.split('/')
new_date = '{}/{}/{}'.format(date_parts[1], date_parts[0], date_parts[2])`
However, there are more elegant ways to do this by using `datetime` module.